# jQuery regex to remove non-numeric characters isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I've been trying to validate a quantity field by using regex to determine on keyup whether or not the value contains any non-numeric characters, yet for some reason (even though i've copied straight up someone elses to test) it does not work. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="quanText" maxlength="2" value="0"></input>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#quanText").keyup(function(){
    $(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PNaJt/

**EDIT**
I also know it isn't working because i tried `.replace(/.*/, '');` which should just make the field blank whenever i type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable - you'll need to do

```
var value= $(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '');
$(this).val(value);
```

the replace() function is going to return you the replaced string which you then have to set back on 'this'

Comment: Oh i see so you need to set the value elsewhere first, then change the contents of it to the new value?

Comment: `.val()` effectively gives you a copy of the text rather than a reference to it.

Comment: val() will return a copy of the value in the field.  In practice, I believe it will be a string.  Strings cannot be modified, any "edits" done via regex will return a new string object that will have the edits applied.

Comment: you do not need to var the value: `$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));`

Answer (score 1):

I use a couple of classes on inputs with some jQuery attached:

```
$("input.intgr").keyup(function (e) { // Filter non-digits from input value.
    if (/\D/g.test($(this).val())) $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, ''));
});
$("input.nmbr").keyup(function (e) { // Filter non-numeric from input value.
    var tVal=$(this).val();
    if (tVal!="" && isNaN(tVal)){
        tVal=(tVal.substr(0,1).replace(/[^0-9\.\-]/, '')+tVal.substr(1).replace(/[^0-9\.]/, ''));
        var raVal=tVal.split(".")
        if(raVal.length>2)
            tVal=raVal[0]+"."+raVal.slice(1).join("");
        $(this).val(tVal);
    } 
});
```